# HTML Mobile web application responds slowly

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, web

I'm developing my first cross-platform web app and after packing my app to different devices (either Android or IPhone) i have discovered an issue of "input controls that responds slowly". For example: a button click doesn't respond smoothly, and there's a short delay (because of touch event on background?).

Anyway after investigating a little more, i saw that there is a way to handle that with Google UI inputs (hope I understand that right) and now it seems bit more complicated than i thought (such as binding touch events).

1. I would like to know, what is the conventional way to make my app respond on the different mobile devices as smooth as it does on my PC's browser?
2. Also, I'm guessing there are few more things i should know and I believe i'll encounter it later, feel free to provide me any extra details.

As I said, this is my first app :}

Comment: you can use ontouchstart instead of onclick to avoid the delay, but be careful: you can then nolonger scroll/pinch on that element. you can also try the fastclick script.

Comment: and what about all the other inputs? and, should i also implement the onclick behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The problem of developing html based applications for android devices comes to hardware acceleration. Most of android devices doesn support hardaware acceleration for html based application even if you do some tricks you can find. (Using translate3d, etc). I would strongly suggest that if you want to get a smooth experience onto your app, you shoulh develope it on java using android SDK. I´ve been trying to get the best posible experience on html5  based application for android/iOs but i ended up working with the sdk.

Comment: Sounds like you refute the essence of developing applications that fit all devices. I still do not understand how is it said that it's possible to develop a html5 web cross-platform app and achieve a smooth behavior.. I'm sure I can find apps that behave as I try to create.

Comment: Sounds like should give it a shoot to android sdk and you would be surprised how, when it comes to compatibility, works perfectly fine. If you are trying a simple app with a couple of screens and not much more than a menu list, your are on the right way. I must insist you should research a bit more about scalability and compatibilty. hope it helps.

Comment: First thanks for your explanations here. The thing I don't have the option to develop to both android and iPhone device separately, and a cross platform app seemed a better way for me. could you please explain how does it still said that HTML5 app should behave well on devices?

Comment: Yes. If you want a native application for both android and ios ill recommend you to use steroids (not anabolics :P). Steroids, like phonegap, Brings you and easy development framework for html5/css3 based applications. I woudl go for steroids because it gives you some tools that would let you modularize your application into the MVC pattern and in a easy way. Steroids its based on Node.js (The free-events-oriented-javascript server). Its really easy to get started with it but im here to help anytime you need. Im really sorry for my english (No im not xD). Hope it helps.

Comment: Your English is fine thanks :) but you didn't quite answer my question, i do use PhoneGap, and currently i only have a simple client side html page (which runs slow), what i asked you was Basically how do people DO develop with HTML5 and achieve no slowniness ? (consider the fact there are html games also which runs perfectly..)

Comment: Do you have any animation running on that application? But the way,nsorry im answering late.